# If I buy an iPad 3 on Verizon, can I use my existing SIM?

Tags: ipad, cellular-carriers, lte

I already have a Verizon 4G LTE phone with a LTE SIM card (or whatever its called). If I purchase a Verizon iPad 3 from Craigslist, can I put my own SIM card in there and use my current data plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **YES**. I purchased a Verizon iPad 3 from someone on craigslist, I then tried cutting the sim card from my Android 4G LTE phone ... fail. I bought a new sim card and ordered a Noosy from Amazon, cut the new micro-sim and VOILA, it worked! Unlimited data on my iPad 3 :)

You can see how i did it here:
http://inboxi.us/ipad